# issue with emsdk on mac

Tags: python, wasm-pack, emsdk

I am trying to setup emsdk on mac with the following command:

```
./emsdk install latest
```

I cloned the repo from git.  However, I get the following error upon running the command mentioned above:

```
** NOTICE **: The default SDK changed from `fastcomp` to `upstream`.
If you have problems, or wish to revert back to fastcomp for some other reason
you can add `-fastcomp` to explicitly install that fastcomp-based
SDK, .e.g ./emsdk install latest-fastcomp.

Installing SDK 'sdk-releases-upstream-b024b71038d1291ed7ec23ecd553bf2c0c8d6da6-64bit'..
Installing tool 'releases-upstream-b024b71038d1291ed7ec23ecd553bf2c0c8d6da6-64bit'..
Error: Downloading URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/mac/b024b71038d1291ed7ec23ecd553bf2c0c8d6da6/wasm-binaries.tbz2': <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)>
Warning: Possibly SSL/TLS issue. Update or install Python SSL root certificates (2048-bit or greater) supplied in Python folder or https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ and try again.
Installation failed!
```

I have tried running the following to fix this but it did not solve the issue.

```
pip install certifi
```

Any other suggestions to fix the issue would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upgrade the python version to 3.8.0 using pyenv.  The upgrade helped me with the certificate issue.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.8.0

pyenv global 3.8.0
```

or if inside the emsdk directory:

```
pyenv local 3.8.0
```

The command `./emsdk install latest` ran successfully after the python upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, this error is caused by a python error. So, you can only modify the python script file: emsdk.py, add following two lines to resolve this error:

> import ssl
>
> ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

A hint: you must insert above two lines before any function definition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).